# Can anyone please tell me why this query isn't producing the correct answers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

Steve Ford helped me with this query below. (Thanks again Steve).

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SC.IsCorrect = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalQuestions,
  COUNT(SA.AnswerID) AS TotalCorrect,
  CAST(COUNT(SA.AnswerID) AS Float) / 
  SUM(CASE WHEN SC.IsCorrect = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 100 As Percentage
  FROM SurveyQuestions SQ
  INNER JOIN SurveyChoices SC ON SQ.QuestionId = SC.QuestionID
  LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers SA ON SA.QuestionId = SC.QuestionID 
  AND SA.ChoiceID = SC.ChoiceID
  AND SA.UserName = 'John.Doe'
  WHERE SC.IsCorrect = 1 
  AND SQ.SurveyID = 10
```

and below is his fiddle demo.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c642/1

The query is intended to display survey results in following format:

Total Questions:**_**     Total Correct:**_**          Percent Correct ***_***

For the most part it works.

However, it still doesn't handle checkboxes correctly.

For instance, there is a field name in SurveyQuestions table called AnswerType.

The values are **M** for Multiple choice answers like checkboxes where a user can check one or more boxes.
**S** for Single answers like radio button choices. Here, a user can only choose one answer.
Finally, T for Freetext where a user can just type in whatever values they prefer.

We don't really care that much about the T answerType.

Steve's code computes the values of Checkboxes correctly.

There is another field called IsCorrect.

Any correct answer, be it single choice or multiple choice has a value of 1 stored in isCorrect bit data type.

If the answer is not correct, isCorrect has a value of 0.

The only issue that I see with Steve's query is that if the value is isCorrect = 1 then it treats that as a question in itself.

As a result, if you check for instance 2 checkboxes, and check them as correct answers, Steve's code treats those 2 separate questions.

Anyway to treat answertYpe of M as one question regardless of how much boxes are checked as correct answers?

Thanks guys for all the assistance here.

Comment: Why don't you adjust your fiddle to show some data that comes out "wrong" instead of describing it with a word problem? Do you know anyone who liked word problems in school? Me neither. Show us the data.

Comment: @AaronBertrand, the information is already there in fiddle.

If you go to the fiddle, you notice the code that is displaying totalQuestions `SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN SC.IsCorrect = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TotalQuestions`

You will also see at the bottom that the output says 3 questions when infact there are 2 questions, one of which was multiple choice and two were chosen as correct Answers (where isCorrect=1). However, the code treated the correct answers as 2 different questions plus the other question. I don't know what else to add when the information is already there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I am not 100% sure on your logic, as to how you would treat the case where there are 3 correct choices and only 2 of them are chosen, or if there are only 2 correct choices and 3 are chosen in total, does this make the question incorrect?

This logic you would have to decide, but I think you need to look at your data on a question by question basis, i.e. check how many correct options there are, how many correct options were given, then you can analyse the data as a whole, the only logic that should change is the scenarios described above:

```
WITH Questions AS
(   SELECT  SQ.QuestionID,
            CorrectChoices = COUNT(NULLIF(SC.IsCorrect, 0)),
            ChoicesGiven = COUNT(SA.ChoiceID),
            CorrectChoicesGiven = COUNT(CASE WHEN SA.ChoiceID IS NOT NULL AND SC.IsCorrect = 1 THEN 1 END)
    FROM    SurveyQuestions SQ
            INNER JOIN SurveyChoices SC 
                ON SQ.QuestionId = SC.QuestionID
            LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers SA 
                ON SA.QuestionId = SC.QuestionID 
                AND SA.ChoiceID = SC.ChoiceID
                AND SA.UserName = 'John.Doe'
    WHERE   SQ.SurveyID = 10
    GROUP BY SQ.QuestionID
)
SELECT  TotalQuestions = COUNT(*),
        TotalCorrect = COUNT(CASE WHEN CorrectChoicesGiven = CorrectChoices THEN 1 END),
        PercentCorrect = CAST(100.0 * COUNT(CASE WHEN ChoicesGiven = CorrectChoices THEN 1 END) / COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)),
        TotalCorrect2 = SUM(CorrectChoicesGiven),
        PercentCorrect = CAST(100.0 * SUM(CorrectChoicesGiven) / SUM(CorrectChoices) AS DECIMAL(5, 2))
FROM    Questions;
```

**[Updated example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c642/109)**

---

**EDIT**

Based on the logic in your comment, that for every correct answer missed in a multiple choice the score is reduced by a proportional percentage, similarly for any incorrect answer given, the rules become as follows (in all examples the numbers refer to a multichoice question where there are 3 possible correct answers)

- If the number of correct answers given matches the total correct
  answers, and no incorrect answers are chosen then the score is 100%
- If the number of correct answers given matches the total correct
  answers, but additional incorrect answers are given then the score is
  reduced by the incorrect choices as a percentage of the total correct
  choices (e.g. chosing 4 options when only 3 are correct will reduce
  the score by 1/3 giving a score of 66.66%)
- If the number of answers
  given exceeds the correct number of answers, and not all correct
  answers are found (e.g 4 answers given, and only 2 correct), this
  would reduce the score by 1 for the extra answer, and one for the
  correct answer missed, giving a reduction of 2/3, so a score of 33%

This whole method can be simplified to the following equation (ensuring 0 is lowest answer possible);

```
(Correct answers given - Extra answers given) / Total Correct answers
```

The flaw in this method is that in a question with 3 possible correct answers, the user can get one correct and still score 0 if they give 3 incorrect options. An alternative, simpler method would be the user gets a score as the percentage of the greater of choices they gave and the correct answers, so in the previous example the user would get 25% (1 correct answer out of 4 selections), if they only chose 1 answer out of 3 and it was right they would still get 33% because they have chosen less than the correct number of answers. I have included this method as Score2 and Percentage2 in the below query so you can make a choice

```
WITH Questions AS
(   SELECT  SQ.QuestionID,
            CorrectChoices = COUNT(NULLIF(SC.IsCorrect, 0)),
            ChoicesGiven = COUNT(SA.ChoiceID),
            CorrectChoicesGiven = COUNT(CASE WHEN SA.ChoiceID IS NOT NULL AND SC.IsCorrect = 1 THEN 1 END),
            ExtraChoicesGiven = CASE WHEN COUNT(SA.ChoiceID) > COUNT(NULLIF(SC.IsCorrect, 0)) THEN COUNT(SA.ChoiceID) - COUNT(NULLIF(SC.IsCorrect, 0)) ELSE 0 END
    FROM    SurveyQuestions SQ
            INNER JOIN SurveyChoices SC 
                ON SQ.QuestionId = SC.QuestionID
            LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers SA 
                ON SA.QuestionId = SC.QuestionID 
                AND SA.ChoiceID = SC.ChoiceID
                AND SA.UserName = 'John.Doe'
    WHERE   SQ.SurveyID = 10
    GROUP BY SQ.QuestionID
), QuestionScores AS
(   SELECT  QuestionID,
            Score = CASE WHEN CorrectChoicesGiven - ExtraChoicesGiven < 0 THEN 0
                        ELSE CAST(CorrectChoicesGiven - ExtraChoicesGiven AS FLOAT) / CorrectChoices
                    END,
            Score2 = ISNULL(CAST(CorrectChoicesGiven AS FLOAT) / NULLIF(CASE WHEN ChoicesGiven > CorrectChoices THEN ChoicesGiven ELSE CorrectChoices END, 0), 0)
    FROM    Questions
)
SELECT  TotalQuestions = COUNT(*),
        TotalCorrect = SUM(Score),
        PercentCorrect = CAST(100.0 * SUM(Score) / COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2)),
        TotalCorrect2 = SUM(Score2),
        PercentCorrect2 = CAST(100.0 * SUM(Score2) / COUNT(*) AS DECIMAL(5, 2))
FROM    QuestionScores;
```

**[Updated SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c642/140)**

Comment: Thank you very much sir for not just taking your time to write the code but for detailed explanation.

Your code produces the correct questions - YEA.

It also produces the correct percentage.

However, it does show how comlex computing checkbox values are.

It shows TotalCorrect with a different correct value and TotalCorrect2 with different value. This one, is the Checkbox value.

I think I can live with this. I just have to explain how the computing is done.

Comment: How you would treat the case where there are 3 correct choices and only 2 of them are chosen, or if there are only 2 correct choices and 3 are chosen in total. Does this make the whole question wrong?

Comment: Sorry been busy testing your code.

If there are 3 correct choices and user picks two, then user gets 2/3 or 75% of that ONE question correct.

If there are 2 correct choices and 3 are chosen, then the user get's punished trying to trick the process by substracting that one from the correct answers, thereby giving the user 1 out ot 2 for 50%.

Excellent question!

Comment: you are a SQL God sir.

I salute you. What is the difference between the query at top and the query at bottom?

 I read your excellent detailed explanations. Very nice.

Much appreciated sir.

All efforts in resolving this are very much appreciated.

I will accept this as answer. You guys have dedicated so much time to helping a stranger. THANK YOU ALL.

Comment: In the top query `TotalCorrect ` and `PercentageCorrect` are based on the logic that **ALL** choices must be correct, there are no part marks, `TotalCorrect2` is a total of all choices, this gives questions unequal weightings, so a question with two correct choices gets 2 marks, and each correct choice the user makes gets 1 mark, so if you had two questions, one with one answer one with 2 answers the total score would be 3, and if the single choice was answered incorrectly and the multiple choice correctly the final score would be 66%.

Comment: The bottom query is as you requested, where each question has a maximum score of 1, and this is based on the total number of correct choices given, and the total number of incorrect choices given.

Answer (score 1):

This is a nested query.  The inner-most query is joining questions to all possible answers and then left-join to the actual choices made by the user.  The counts of actual correct POSSIBLE answers based on the choices table only, then the actual CORRECT ENTERED from the answers table.  I am getting a count of CORRECT answers AND a count of ACTUAL answers provided.  This way, the final "correct" answer is where the question correct answer count matches the correct answer count by the user ... AND the total answers PROVIDED by the user is the same.  This will handle instances of a question with 2 correct answers and a person picking 3 choices of which 2 are correct... so 2 = 2 is ok, but will fail when it compares to 3 choices -- the user OVER PICKED.  Also handles if a user only picks one choice and that one is correct... so 2 = 1 would fail regardless of how many possible correct answers were available.

The grouping is per question, so those that are single will only ever have a possible count of correct answers of 1 and 1 possible correct answer (or not).  The multiple will be rolled-up so it too would be a single entry question.

I then roll these totals up to a single row of FinalCorrectAnswers and TotalQuestions.

Then

```
SELECT
      FinalCorrectAnswers,
      TotalQuestions,
      ( FinalCorrectAnswers / ( 1.000 * TotalQuestions )) * 100.00 as Percentage
from
(
SELECT
      SUM( case when AnsByType.CorrectChoices = AnsByType.CorrectAnswers
                 AND AnsByType.CorrectChoices = AnsByType.TotalAnswersProvided
              then 1.000 else 0.000 end) as FinalCorrectAnswers,
      sum( 1 ) as TotalQuestions
   from
      ( SELECT 
              SQ.QuestionID,
              SUM( case when SCM.IsCorrect = 1 then 1 else 0 end ) as CorrectChoices,
              SUM( case when SCM.IsCorrect = 1 
                         AND NOT MAnswers.ChoiceID IS NULL
                      then 1 else 0 end ) as CorrectAnswers,
              COUNT( MAnswers.ChoiceID ) as TotalAnswersProvided
           from 
              SurveyQuestions SQ
                 Join SurveyChoices SCM
                    ON SQ.QuestionID = SCM.QuestionID
                    LEFT JOIN SurveyAnswers MAnswers
                       ON SCM.QuestionID = MAnswers.QuestionID
                       AND SCM.ChoiceID = MAnswers.ChoiceID
                       AND MAnswers.UserName = 'John.Doe'
           where
              SQ.SurveyID = 10
           group by
              SQ.QuestionID ) AnsByType  ) FinalSum
```

Based on the sample data from SQLFiddle, I believe the correct answer is 0% correctly answered.  If you run [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c642/134) from the same sample set you listed in your answer, question 8 had a single choice answer, but the user did not enter that value.  For question 9 was a multi-choice answer, but the person only answered ONE of the correct answers.  So, since BOTH were not correctly answered, the answer was wrong, thus both answers incorrect and a zero percentage score.

Comment: fantastic explanations. However, the code isn't working correctly.

I have 2 questions. It is capturing the 2 questions with TotalQuestions 2.0000. But finalAnswers of 1.000 and percentage of 2.00000 are incorrect.

GarethD's solution is just about correct. I just have to figure out a way to explain the difference between TotalCorrect1 and TotalCorrect2, and PercentCorrect1 and PercentCorrect2.

I think percentCorrect2 deals with multiple choice anwers.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh, I adjusted the query. I had wrong order of division 2/1 instead of 1/2 and added the * 100 for percentage.

Comment: now, I am getting `incorrect syntax near as` (line 4) and `incorrect syntax near FinalSum` (line 31)

Comment: @ChidiOkeh, I missed removing the "end" clause from the division when I had it as a case/when.

Comment: @ChidiOkeh, updated answer to show correct percentage IS in-fact zero since no correct answer on question 8, and only 1 of 2 correct answers entered on question 9.  Also, there were no choices entered for question 16, so nobody could actually enter a valid answer. And the answer for question 14 was for survey 11, not 10.

Comment: thank you so much sir for all your help and efforts.

I am still testing with the same data as the one on fiddle.

I have 2 questions, one single choice and one multiple choice.

So, it should say 2 questions and your code correctly says 2 questions.

However, given that 3 of 4 multiple choice answers are correct, plus a single choice answer which is correct.

I would like to think that the overall percentage is better than 50%, no?

Comment: @ChidiOkeh, It would only be over 50% if you gave partial credit.  However, from the sample data from that sqlfiddle thread, only 2 answers were even provided, and no choices were inserted for question 16 (part of survey 10 questions), so there would never BE a join result of choices since nobody could pick anything.  However, if your production sample data has it, then you should be good.  Personally, if you don't have all the correct answers, it's wrong.  if you want to "weight" an answer for partial credit, then that's another calculation altogether.

Comment: I just updated fiddle again just now. Sorry it took so long because the thing was asking me to reduce size of ddl to 8000.

In this dump, there are 2 questions. One is multiple choice where 3 of those are correct. However, the user checked 3 boxes but one of the boxes is wrong. This is done for testing purposes only.

In the other question, the user's choice is correct

Comment: @ChidiOkeh, as suggested by the page and so many comments, you might want to open a chat for this discussion... Also, there is no link showing your updated sqlfiddle example with the new data.  I'll be out for a while but can check in after.